# Include only few package in Maven dependency

Tags: maven, bean-validation

I need to include bean-validation API in my java project and I used below maven dependency for same

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

But the entire javax package (annotations,faces etc.. )is getting downloaded to my repository which I don't want for certain reasons

How to include only validation-api from maven

Comment: You have defined a dependency which means you need to compile/build your code and so it is downloaded and put into your local repository. To be honest I don't understand your problem? What does this: `which I don't want for certain reasons...` mean? What are the reasons?

Comment: I need only validation-api artifact . entire javax package getting downloaded to my local repository that is my issue

Comment: Based on the given dependency https://search.maven.org/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api/2.0.1.Final/jar it shows that validation-api only has a test dependency but no other transitive dependencies. So I suppose you have other dependencies in your project which have javax package dependencies.